# Powerbuilder WebApp Access on my website

Tags: web-applications, deployment, powerbuilder

I'm running PB11.5.
I just upoaded my webapp to my website.
Cannot seem to run it from website, but I can run it from my PC.
I'm using a MS Access DB.

Comment: There is not enough detail to answer your question.  Do you get any error messages?  Can you give a more detailed description of the steps you took deploy your app?

Answer (score 1):

As Colin says, the information you've provided at this point is a little sparse, but that may reflect the problem. You only mention uploading files. In fact, there are several steps involved in getting a PB WebForms app to run, including registering .NET assemblies, adjusting a system path, etc.... The [Deploying Applications and Components to .NET](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.pb_11.5/title.htm) manual should be able to get you further than what it sounds like you've achieved.

Good luck,

Terry.